# Contact Form 7 Displaying Huge White Space at the Bottom

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

My Contact Form 7 is displaying a huge white space at the bottom. This does not look good. You can see the below screenshot.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tgsrV.jpg)

I saw that `wpcf7-response-output wpcf7-display-none` is taking most of the white spaces, but I cannot remove it as this class contains the error message.

URL - https://iinnovatemag.com/blog/networking/coworking/what-is-coworking-space/

Do you know what can I do to remove (or at least significantly reduce) the white space?

Thanks in advance,
Vaibhav

Comment: Please check my answer, and replay your feedback.

Comment: My answer is working for you?

Comment: You should at least accept answer for developer encouragement.

Answer (score 1):

Add Below css in your theme css.

```
div.wpcf7-response-output {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0px !important;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

div.wpcf7-validation-errors {
    padding: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this code helps you to overcome the problem

```
div.wpcf7-response-output {
        padding: 0;
    }
    .wpcf7-AbovePost {
        margin-bottom: 0px;
    }
    #wpcf7-f7841-p7824-o1 p:nth-child(4) {
        margin: 0 !important;
    }
```